# Invalid name: "@angular/cli" when do npm install

Tags: angular, npm-install

I need to install angular/cli package, but got error

$sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

But I got the following error

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0

npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"

npm ERR! node v6.6.0

npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3


npm ERR! Invalid name: "@angular/cli"

npm ERR!

npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:

npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>


npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     /Users/jim/Downloads/project/admin/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it looks weird as I configured angular/cli in package.json, but it result from npm version is outdated, so I did the npm update

$sudo npm update npm -g

Also the following commands can help check versions and do a clean install via "**uninstall -> clean -> install**".

$npm --v

$node -v

$sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli

$sudo npm cache clean

$sudo npm install -g angular-cli@latest